Switch repository based on environment
In my local development environment, I need to use my local repo. But when I build in cloud, I need to use remote repo.
Can someone please help me to achieve this as I'm new to gradle?
EDIT:
This is how I defined Repos. I need to use local repo in local machine and use remote url in Cloud.
repositories {

   maven {
        url 'remote-url'
        credentials {
            username "xyz"
            password = "xyz"
        }
    }   
    
   mavenLocal()
   mavenCentral()
}


I don't know if I get it right but if you mean to have it work locally as offline you can use the gradle command as this on your local machine.
gradle build --offline

this will only use your local repo and not download anything from the internet.
Edit: you can pass a variable like this
./gradlew build -PuseLocalRepo=true

and use it in the call of the gradle repo like this.

 if (project.hasProperty('useLocalRepo') && project.useLocalRepo.toBoolean()) {
    mavenLocal()
} else {
    mavenCentral()
}



I have edited my answer, please check now if that helps.

This is what exactly I was looking for! thank you!
